# CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction;

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I have no idea what I'm looking at here. I tried to trace down the problem to some kind of animation, but I don't know where that could be. How can I track down where this is coming from?

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923ecb95 _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 219
1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923ec76d _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 273
2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923ec60a _ZN2CA11Transaction9set_valueEj12_CAValueTypePKv + 40
3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923ec59e +[CATransaction setDisableActions:] + 38
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7fff6e -[NSScrollerImp _updateLayerGeometry] + 67
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a7ff54d -[NSScroller(NSInternal2) _replaceScrollerImp] + 368
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a897828 -[NSScroller initWithCoder:] + 305
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff89e92a09 _decodeObjectBinary + 2741
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff89e91db4 _decodeObject + 226
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a719760 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1103
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a71afad -[NSControl initWithCoder:] + 50
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a89772d -[NSScroller initWithCoder:] + 54
12  Foundation                          0x00007fff89e92a09 _decodeObjectBinary + 2741
13  Foundation                          0x00007fff89e91db4 _decodeObject + 226
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a719760 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1103
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ae115ee -[NSCollectionView initWithCoder:] + 114
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923ecb95 _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 219
1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923ec76d _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 273
2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923f38ab _ZN2CA5Layer13thread_flags_EPNS_11TransactionE + 37
3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923f37e3 _ZN2CA5Layer4markEPNS_11TransactionEjj + 79
4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923f374a _ZN2CA5Layer25set_needs_display_in_rectERK6CGRect + 392
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a8ff47d -[_NSViewBackingLayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 206
6   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff923f359f -[CALayer setNeedsDisplay] + 62
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a8ff3a9 -[_NSViewBackingLayer setNeedsDisplay] + 73
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a900bc8 -[NSView(NSInternal) _setLayerNeedsDisplayInViewRect:] + 566
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a73caad -[NSView setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 809
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a73c672 -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:] + 79
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a755648 -[NSButtonCell setTitle:] + 131
12  myOSXApp                          0x00000001000087cb -[MyWindowController updateOutlineNodeCount:] + 187
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d5be47a _CFXNotificationPost + 2554
14  Foundation                          0x00007fff89e8c846 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
15  myOSXApp                          0x00000001000104f9 -[IconViewModel setChecked:] + 153
```

Answer (score 3):

The backtrace shows you what code of your App lead to the problem.

```
myOSXApp                          0x00000001000087cb -[MyWindowController updateOutlineNodeCount:] + 187 
myOSXApp                          0x00000001000104f9 -[IconViewModel setChecked:] + 153
```

I'm assuming that you post a notification from a different thread that is not the main thread.
Without more context this is hard to tell...

Be aware that threading and notifications to not mix well.

You seem to post a notification in setChecked: and this code is not running on the main thread.